# Recursive Sierpinsky Triangle - StackOverflow error

Tags: java, recursion

I got my code running so far, except for the recursive part. I get a StackOverflow error and I really don't get why, or how to fix it. When I work through the code it seems logically fine.

```
public class SierpinskiTriangle {
public static int SIZE = 1000;

JFrame frame;
JPanel panel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public void display() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    panel = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            paintSierpinskiTriangle(20, 20, 360, (Graphics2D)g);
        }
    };
    panel.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            panel.repaint();
        }
    });
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(SIZE, SIZE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SierpinskiTriangle triangle = new SierpinskiTriangle();
    triangle.display();
}

public static void paintSierpinskiTriangle(int x, int y, int s, Graphics2D g) {
    g.drawLine(x, y, x+s, y);
    g.drawLine(x, y, x, y+s);
    g.drawLine(x+s, y, x, y+s);

    paintSierpinskiTriangle(x, y, s/2, g);
    paintSierpinskiTriangle(x+s/2, y, s/2, g);
    paintSierpinskiTriangle(x, y+s/2, s/2, g);

}
}
```

Comment: How many times do you think `paintSierpinkskiTriangle()` is called everytime your `JPanel` `repaint`s?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it.

Comment: I think you are missing some checks in `paintSierpinskiTriangle`, you will **never** stop recursing.

Comment: What don't you get? The question I asked?

Comment: Got it now, thanks luk :)

Comment: @luk2302 You should provide an answer so OP can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some conditions to return from the `paintSierpinskiTriangle`method.

Without any conditions, it will keep calling itself infinitely, even if s = 0, which is what causes the Error.